# Generate random letters containing a word

Tags: random, kotlin

There is a popular game called [4 Pics 1 Word](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.lotum.whatsinthefoto.us) that presents to the user 4 pictures representing a common word. The word has to be typed by selecting some of the 9 random letters appearing below the images.

The German version of this app has an annoying bug. When the random letters contain a letter from the set ÄÖÜß, it is guaranteed that the desired word contains this letter. This is unfair. The algorithm for picking the random letters seems to be: take the letters of the word and fill up the rest with equally distributed letters from the alphabet A-Z. This algorithm can be implemented fast but often selects a Q without the corresponding U.

I wanted to see whether it is possible to generate random letters that are "more naturally random". The first step to reach this goal is to pick the letters according to the frequency they appear in the corpus of all words to be guessed. The following code does exactly that.

I know that the code is slow and can be optimized for speed in several ways. That's not the point of the code. The main purpose is to serve as the reference implementation that is as simple to understand (and mathematically verify) as possible. It should clearly demonstrate the underlying concepts and ideas. It can later be compared with more optimized versions of the code, to verify that the probabilities in the optimized code are still correct.

```
package de.roland_illig.wordprob

import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatThrownBy
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Disabled
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

/**
 * Given a [word] from a set of [words], generate [n] random letters
 * that contain all the letters from the [word].
 * The returned letters should be "as random as possible".
 */
fun randomLetters(
    words: Set<String>,
    word: String,
    n: Int,
    rnd: (Int) -> Int
): String {
    require(word in words) { word }
    require(n >= word.length) { "$n < $word" }

    val wordCodePoints = word.codePoints().toArray()
    val allLetters = words.joinToString("").codePoints().toArray()
    while (true) {
        val codePoints = IntArray(n) { allLetters[rnd(allLetters.size)] }
        if (codePoints.containsAll(wordCodePoints))
            return String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.size)
    }
}

private fun IntArray.containsAll(sub: IntArray): Boolean {
    val remaining = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()
    for (cp in this) remaining[cp] = (remaining[cp] ?: 0) + 1

    for (cp in sub) {
        val rem = remaining[cp] ?: return false
        if (rem == 0) return false
        remaining[cp] = rem - 1
    }
    return true
}

class WordProbabilitiesKtTest {

    private val seqs = mutableListOf<Seq>()

    @AfterEach
    fun tearDown() {
        for (seq in seqs) {
            check(seq.i == seq.ns.size) {
                "partly used sequence ${seq.ns.asList()}"
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun containsAll() {
        fun Array<Int>.containsAll(sub: Array<Int>) =
            toIntArray().containsAll(sub.toIntArray())

        assertThat(arrayOf(1, 2, 3).containsAll(arrayOf(1, 2, 3))).isTrue()
        assertThat(arrayOf(1, 2, 3).containsAll(arrayOf(1, 2))).isTrue()
        assertThat(arrayOf(1, 2, 3).containsAll(arrayOf())).isTrue()
        assertThat(arrayOf(1, 2, 3).containsAll(arrayOf(1, 1))).isFalse()
        assertThat(arrayOf(1, 2, 3).containsAll(arrayOf(4))).isFalse()
    }

    @Test
    fun randomLetters() {
        assertThat(randomLetters(setOf("a", "b"), "a", 1, seq(0))).isEqualTo("a")
        assertThat(randomLetters(setOf("a", "b"), "b", 1, seq(1))).isEqualTo("b")
        assertThat(randomLetters(setOf("a", "b"), "a", 1, seq(1, 0))).isEqualTo("a")
        assertThat(randomLetters(setOf("a", "b"), "a", 2, seq(1, 0))).isEqualTo("ba")

        assertThat(randomLetters(
            setOf("cat", "dog"),
            "cat",
            3,
            seq(3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 0, 2)
        )).isEqualTo("act")
    }

    @Test
    fun `randomLetters, generator exhausted`() {
        assertThatThrownBy { randomLetters(setOf("a", "b"), "a", 2, seq(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)) }
            .isExactlyInstanceOf(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException::class.java)
    }

    @Test
    @Disabled("Tests the test code, fails too late, at tearDown")
    fun `randomLetters, generator partly used`() {
        randomLetters(setOf("a", "b"), "a", 2, seq(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 7))
    }

    private fun seq(vararg ns: Int): (Int) -> Int {
        val seq = Seq(*ns).also { seqs += it }
        return { seq.next() }
    }

    private class Seq(internal vararg val ns: Int) {
        internal var i = 0
        fun next(): Int = ns[i].also {
            check(i < ns.size) { "reached end of ${ns.asList()}" }
            i++
        }
    }
}
```

A future version of that code might take into account that in German, the letter Q is always followed by a U. This could be based on a Markov chain. But for now I am satisfied with fixing the unfair distribution of single letters.

Comment: Other then advising you should  to look into Property-testing, I don't have any advice...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you search for letters until you've got all letters of the word. However, that might take forever. It's better to first add the letters of word and then fill up with random letters from the word list. Finally, **shuffle** the characters. You could remove the word from the list of words or not, that's up to you.